# Automapper isn't using extension methods for mapping

Tags: automapper, extension-methods

I have automapper setup like this

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingAssembly).Assembly, typeof(AssemblyWithExtensionMethods).Assembly);
```

And in one of my profiles

```
public class UserModuleMapper : Profile {
  public UserModuleMapper() {
    IncludeSourceExtensionMethods(typeof(UserGroup));
    CreateMap<UserGroup, UserGroupDto>(MemberList.Destination);              
  }
}
```

And I have defined the extension method as

```
public static List<string> GetRoleNames(this UserGroup group) {
  return group.UserGroupRoles.Select(x => x.Role.Name).ToList();
}
```

I have a property on DTO defined as

```
public List<string> RoleNames { get; set; }
```

As per the automapper documentation, I have made the following assumptions:

1. IncludeSourceExtensionMethods, which include extension methods while mapping
2. while mapping it will also look for methods with prefix `Get`

But when I validate the automapper extension I get error for unmapped property

> Unmapped properties: RoleNames

What is missing in my configuration, `automapper` should detect the extension method.

I have tried (a) remove GET from the method name, but still does not work (b) moving `CreateMap` before or after the `IncludeSourceExtensionMethods` to see if sequence matters, but none of it helped.

Comment: Right after the last block of code you wrote: *"As per the automapper documentation"*, it would help a lot if you could provide a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With in few minutes after posting the question I got the answer by carefully looking at [this issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2276) on Github

The issue was with below statement

```
      IncludeSourceExtensionMethods(typeof(UserGroup));
```

the type mentioned here should be of extension class

```
      IncludeSourceExtensionMethods(typeof(UserGroupExtensions));
```

Not deleting the question, as it might help someone in future.